# How to monitoring log on multi server with log.io

Tags: monitor, log

I'm install and configure `log.io` on one server that okey.
This is image of: [web of log server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huzRi.png)

But now I want to monitoring multi remote server with one master server.
Any links or suggestion helping me on this task, would be appreciated.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first, you should check architecture of `log.io`. This is image of it:

[image: Architecture log.io]

From image you can see, In `each server` must have one `Harvesters`. So you must install `log.io` in all server with command:

`npm install -g log.io --user "root"`

But with Master Server(ex IP: 10.0.0.86) you run 2 service is:

```
log.io-server & (only run in Master Server)
log.io-harvester &
```

In Another Remote Server(I call it is client Server) you must modify line `server` in file `~/.log.io/harvester.conf` is:

```
server: {
  host: '10.0.0.86(IP Master Server)',
  port: 28777
}
```

and start service `harvester` on `all client server` with:

```
log.io-harvester &
```

And you remember allow `IP Client Server` to port `28777` & `28778` on firewall:

```
ufw allow from 10.0.0.85(IP Client Server)  to any port 22
```

The end, You connect browser to `http://10.0.0.86(IP Master Server):28778` see multi server in here. If you not see client Server on browser you can `Clear Cache` or `Ctl + f5(refresh browser)`.

Comment: Ok, I'm will trying, but have problems is log.io not show old log, when I create new task browser its new blank and not old log.